# vb.net Algorithm for drawing tree diagrams

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, tree, drawing, diagram

This is kindy hard to explain,

Am looking for an Algorithms that will take object that a linked to multiple other object and work out the best location to draw each object based on there links.

this would generate a tree like diagram.

So i have Object 1 then hast 10 link, one of these link is object 2 that has 5 link but object 1 link to one of object2s links and such link.

so i would have some thing like this

Object1 ------------ Object2
       \                        /
         \                    /
           \                /
             Object 3

But this is on a 100% bigger scale with unlimited number of objects and links.

Any ideas how i would go about working out the best location on my form for each object?

Comment: So you have any code already for the objects? Which technology with vb.net do you plan to draw (I assume you mean a picture?) the trees in a win forms, asp.net, Silverlight, WPF?

Comment: this is a win form app, I have the code to create the object and links. Am just trying to layout the diagram that it creates better as with the current version it just creates the object side by side but drawing squares on a picture box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphviz is a library doing such thing.  They have [references to papers](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php) in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[There are several approaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing#Layout_methods), none of which are trivial. There might well exist libraries for it, though.